# Hyper-V host virtual switch preference

Tags: networking, routing, virtualization, hyper-v, switch

Couldn't find any decent info online, may be my lack of searching skills.

Situation:

Hyper-V host with external virtual switch (shared with host) and internal virtual switch. IP's received in both external (physical) network and internal (virtual) network.

Problem:

All host traffic is routed over the internal switch network because the metric of this route is lower. Why doesn't it use the external switch network as default? I can change the metric of the internal route to a higher value but then it still uses the internal network's DNS servers. Could not find a way to change the preferred network in the GUI.

Questions:

Why? Seems counter-intuitive to me. Any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I have Hyper-V here and get good Internet network performance via the default switch or external switch - it does not matter so far as I can see.

For LAN transfers, speed will depend on the NIC chosen. Ethernet is still faster than Wireless, but this is not a unique property of Hyper-V

Default is the internal switch or NAT.

If you want an External Switch to be default, set it up in the Hyper-V Network manager (top right of Hyper-V).  The External Switch setup will show you what NIC it is attached to, so you should be able to use the one you want.

Then you have to go to the Guest machine, make sure it is shut down, and then change the Guest machine networking (lower right) to the External Switch. It will always be External (Bridged) after that.

Note that all these settings are in the Hyper-V Manager and not in the Guest

> Could not find a way to change the preferred network in the GUI.

I think you mean "in the Guest Machine" and no, you cannot change which NIC in the guest machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not address the issue I am having. I'll try to explain better.

When you have both an external and internal virtual switch configred on the host, the traffic gets routed over the internal switch first. Instead of taking the external switch as default path, it routes through the VM network's router and then out to the physical router. 

Wich means double NAT, extra overhead, firewall, ...

Comment: Try configuring with just one switch.  To the best of my knowledge wtih Hyper-V, it cannot deat with the complication (2 working host NICs).  I am quite sure the settings I laid out in m answer is a good way to set up Hyper-V

Comment: I have 4 NIC's actually but only one is used for Hyper-V. Using only one switch is not what I want / need.

The "iniability" of Hyper-V when using this is exactly the reason why I ask.

Surely it cannot be that this not adjustable to your preferences.

Comment: Make sure in Hyper-V Switch Setup that the default (NAT) NIC is not setup up to any NIC.  Set up the External Switch as you wish and make sure the setup saves. Then only attach the Guest network to the External Switch. Hyper-V should then just use the one switch.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I am certainly not entirely clear (your question is not really clear) but trying to run a bunch of NICs inside Hyper-V is not going to work as far as I can see using Hyper-V workstation.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned this is on Windows Server

Comment: If you have Hyper-V Workstation (not Base Metal Hypervisor) then I think you can have just one NIC.  Any attempt I make to add another NIC fails at the NIC configuration step.

Comment: Yes, but I am not using Workstation but the Hyper-V role.

Comment: What iwas / is not clear is this:  Are you using Bare Metal Hypervisor?

Comment: Yes, Hyper-V role on Windows server OS or bare metal if you like. 

Anyway, I figured it out. Using Get-NetIPInterface in PS I could see the IPv6 metric for the internal adapter was still lower. After disabling IPv6 on the adapter, it works as expected.
You cannot set the v6 metric using the GUI I think.